# What is the difference between using spark Hive and any other Spark with NoSQL or SQL database?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-hive

I am new to Spark.
I had been trying to use Spark Hive, Spark MySQL or Spark Cassandra.
However, i still don't know the differences between them, which is slower, which is more expensive and what are their disadvantages, how they acctually work.

Can anyone here help me figure out the differences between them and if possible, i also want some examples please!

Thank you everyone!

Comment: It's a broad question - please add more details on what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Sr for the misleading question, I will change the question @AlexOtt

Comment: You cannot keep changing the question to something completely different. You should instead post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a Cassandra database from a Spark application, you need to use the [Spark Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) library. I am not aware of alternative options that would allow you to connect to Cassandra otherwise.

Here's an example that shows how to use the connector from a Spark 3.2 cluster with `spark-shell`:

```
$ spark-shell
  --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.2.0
  --master <master_url>
  --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=cass_ip
  --conf spark.cassandra.auth.username=cass_user
  --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password=cass_pass
  --conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions
```

Here's an example code that you can run in a Spark shell to count the the number of keyspaces:

```
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("system_schema","keyspaces")
println("Row count: " + rdd.count)
```

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Comment: This is not the answer that I try to find but thanks btw.

Comment: That's because you keep changing the question which is a bad thing to do. You should instead post a new question.